# python - string formatting increasing by 1

Tags: python, string, formatting

I'm creating a script which uses os walk to traverse through directories looking for files. The script then writes the name of the file to a txt file. I am having trouble labelling each file. I want each file to have a unique integer assigned to it, so for example:

```
File ID: 1001
File ID: 1002
```

How do I increment the number that is getting written to a txt file?

I tried:

```
num = 0
newNum = 1

f.write('File ID: ' + '%d' + '%d' % (num, newNum))
```

The error says:

```
Type error: function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: The code you posted here does **not** throw that exception.

Comment: Instead, it'll throw `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`. Don't use string concatenation when none is needed; `'File ID: %d%d' % (num, newNum)` will work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this:

```
f.write('File ID: ' + '%d' + '%d' % (num, newNum))
```

should just be

```
f.write('File ID: %d' % (num + newNum))
```

then you have to increment one of them, like this for instance:

```
numNum += 1
```